# CentOS time jumps by multiple seconds — sometimes

Tags: bash, time, centos

I get strange times output when running this shell script on the server CentOS 5 (32 bits).
It's a dedicated server, not a VPS.

#### time.sh

```
#!/bin/bash    
for i in {1..10}
do
NOW=$(date +"%M:%S")
echo "$i $NOW"
done
```

The result is:

```
1 05:27    
2 05:09
3 05:09
4 05:09
5 05:27
6 05:09
7 05:27
8 05:09
9 05:27
10 05:09
```

You see the time jumps on some iterations.
I don't know what the problem is.

I run the script on another server. The result is OK.

```
1 52:58
2 52:58    
3 52:58
4 52:58
5 52:58
6 52:58
7 52:58
8 52:58
9 52:58
10 52:58
```

Comment: My guess is the first server is a virtual server with severe clock issues.

Comment: unlikely, but try increasing the loop to 1000. If there ends up being any change you know that the second server is super fast!

Comment: @TopGunCoder It's not surprising that the second server can run `date` 10 times in one second. What is surprising is the first server regularly oscillating between 9 and 27 for the seconds.

Comment: @chepner No. It's a dedicated server, not a VPS.

Comment: off topic to me but you should check /var/log/messages an other logs, your box may have an OS issue. Try showing the date on it's own line without the subshell call $(...)

Comment: Do you have any output about the clock in dmesg? `dmesg | grep -i "\(clock\|timer\)"`

Comment: Most likely KVM or Zen "dedicated" server. I recommend posting results of running lsmod as a "virtio" listing would indicate a virtualized guest in which the time is drifting.

Comment: Also have a look if ntpd is running. ntpd will sync your time everytime the time differs from a trustet timeserver (this is a weard sentence ^^)

Comment: microseconds have nothing to do with this and should not be mentioned in the question..

Comment: Does the `date` command outside of this script appear to show the correct time?

Comment: How long does it take the script to run?

Comment: Have you compared the sets of NTP or SNTP time servers that the two machines are connected to?  The instability is surprising even if the problem is somehow in the NTP service.  Does it still occur after a reboot?  Is the unstable machine ancient and there's a almost dead backup battery for the hardware timer, and this is giving the problems?  Clutching at straws — that's one reason this is a comment, not an answer.  Dunno if you'd do better on Server Fault or Super User?

Answer (score 0):

This is as issue with CentOS 5.X that has been brought up on the CentOS forums. Here is one of the discussions with some details: https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=14610

The error that you are seeing is most likely in the OS, not in your script. I recommend trying either a newer version of CentOS or a different flavor of Linux if that is practical.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen behavior like this before when there were multiple ntpd processes running and one of them somehow started to drift.

Check the output of pidof ntpd and confirm that there is only one pid listed.  If there are multiple, kill them all and restart ntpd.

```
if (( $( pidof ntpd | wc -w ) != 1 )); then
  echo "Woah there - found multiple ntpd processes..."
  sudo killall ntpd
  sudo /etc/init.d/ntpd start
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't replicate this on my centos 7. So I can only provide a reference measurement running the same script with other software.

```
$ ./testclock.sh 
1 11:36
2 11:36
3 11:36
4 11:36
5 11:36
6 11:36
7 11:36
8 11:36
9 11:36
10 11:36
```

There is a lack of information in this case. The bash script itself does not contain any obvious errors that I can see. Hence the issue is likely to be an outside issue. You need to approach this pragmatically and break down the issue into constituents.

You then need to start finding out the differences in execution between the machine that jitters and the one that provides a correct result. Examples of this is;

- Does the software installations on the machines differ? Run "rpm -qa" and compare the list and versions. If they do differ, check the changelists and bug reports for those particular softwares and every software version in between. Check all software, but begin with the binaries and libraries that you know to be directly related to 'date'.
- Does the hardware differ? In what way? Does that affect time measurement?
- Is the time measurement based on local hardware or a networked service? If networked, are all pool members set to the same time? Are both the servers using the same pools?
- Both ntpd and ntpdate can be used to set time. Ntpd usually does incremental time corrections while ntpdate sets the corrected time instantly. While unlikely that this is the cause since the script runs so quickly, it should still be on the check list.
- If everything is a duplicate softwarewise, networkwise and hardwarewise, then it's probably a hardware issue. Rebooting is of course recommended as a removal of one-time-events, even on a linux distribution.